# Bioacoustic studies

Tags: graduate-school, underwater

What would be the different possible paths to take to learn bioacoustic (especially underwater bioacoustic) ? What about the Master in Bioacoustic at the ENES Lab in Saint Etienne in France ?

Comment: The title "Bioacoustic studies" may be ambiguous, as I thought you was talking about bioacoustic research. Maybe "Bioacoustic university programs" would be better?

Comment: Welcome, Victorine! Your question was closed because it was quite broad and general. I would suggest you edit both the title, as @Noil suggested, and the text of the question to tell us a bit more about what you are looking for - are you looking to go to graduate school? Are you looking to begin a career in bioacoustics?

Answer (score 1):

The [IMBRSea MSc pogram](https://www.imbrsea.eu/) in Marine Biological Resources! It's not a whole program in acoustics, but you can take the [Applied Megafauna Conservation module (semester 3)](https://www.imbrsea.eu/course_filter?field_course_category_target_id=33&field_university_target_id=All&field_course_level_value=All) at ATU in Galway (Ireland) and then choose a thesis focused on underwater acoustics for the second year.

Comment: can you provide links to these sites? That would be helpful

Comment: Thank you very much !